# Count showing different results in Postgresql. Wondering Why

Tags: postgresql

i have this query:

```
select count(distinct(buyer)) from tablename
where date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '220' day)
```

The output is:  `11449`

then i have this query:

```
with cte as (SELECT
    distinct(buyer),

    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '1' day))as day1 ,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '2' day))as day2 ,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '5' day))as day5 ,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '7' day))as day7 ,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '15' day))as day15,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '30' day))as day30,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '60' day))as day60,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '90' day))as day90,
    COUNT(order) FILTER (WHERE date(purchase_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '220' day))as day220

FROM tablename
group by buyer
order by day220 desc)

select count(distinct(buyer)) from cte
```

and the output is `20507`

I was expecting the count to be the same in both queries as I am performing them in the same table, at the same moment.

What am I missing here?  Am I wrong to expect the counts to be the same?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is not a function. Enclosing the column name after the `distinct` keyword with  parentheses achieves nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The second one does not have a primary WHERE clause, so it include distinct buyers from all the rows in the table.  You seem to think that PostgreSQL is going to take the union of all the FILTER (WHERE...) clauses and apply them as the primary WHERE clause, but it does not do that (nor would it be sensible for it to do that).

Also, `order` without double quotes is not a legal name for a column, as `order` is a reserved word.  You should post example queries that can actually be run.

Comment: its order_id, thought this has no impact to understand my question